# Checking a query Result in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my database i have a Table called News. In News i have a column named Link. This link CAN be null. If the article is written by the editors the link will be null , if the editors just want to reference an article from another site then this Link will contain a value.
My task: Make a href to the article. Here i have a problem if my editor writes the article i put a href to that article . If it is not written(so the link is not null) i have to pur that href insteaf. 
I have no idea how to do this, any tips ?
Code:
Display:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownSelect_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="DesDate"> Descending Date </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="AsDate"> Ascending Date </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="AsAlp"> Ascending Alphabetical </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="DesAlp"> Descending Alphabetical </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ListView ID="productList" runat="server" 
                DataKeyNames="NewsID" GroupItemCount="1"
                ItemType="SiteStiri.Models.News" SelectMethod="GetProducts">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table >
                        <tr>
                            <td>No data was returned.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <EmptyItemTemplate>
                    <td/>
                </EmptyItemTemplate>
                <GroupTemplate>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                        <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
                    </tr>
                </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <td runat="server">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="NewsDetails.aspx?newsID=<%#:Item.NewsID%>">
                                        <img src="/Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.ImagePath%>"
                                            width="100" height="75" style="border: solid" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="NewsDetails.aspx?newsID=<%#:Item.NewsID%>">
                                        <p style="color: black;">
                                            <%#:Item.NewsTitle%>
                                        </p>
                                    </a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table style="width:100%;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="width:100%">
                                        <tr id="groupPlaceholder"></tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </div>
```

Behind the page:

```
public IQueryable<News> GetProducts()
        {
            var _db = new SiteStiri.Models.NewsContext();
            IQueryable<News> query = _db.News;

            if ("DesDate".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.ReleaseDate);
            }

            if ("AsDate".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(u => u.ReleaseDate);
            }
            if ("AsAlp".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(u => u.NewsTitle);
            }
            if ("DesApl".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.NewsTitle);
            }

            return query;
        }

        public void DropDownSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetProducts();
            productList.DataBind();
        }
```

How can i put here `<a href="NewsDetails.aspx?newsID=<%#:Item.NewsID%>">` either the page link to my site if Link IS null or the Link of the link IS NOT null?

Comment: Are you saying `NewsID` could be `NULL` ?

Comment: no, there is a Link column in the table and depending on its value(if it is null or not) i want to either make a reference to my page or the page that is saved in the Link column .

Comment: Why don't you set it in the **DB** instead of checking in code? you could set the column as `NOT NULL` and give a default value of *YourURL*.

Comment: would you believe me that 4h ago i thought of that , then got into something else, then i wanted to tackle this problem and i completely forgot that idea ever existed and i didn't thought of it again :D ?

Comment: most stupid post i have ever opened ...sorry. Well it there was a method that could check in code it isn't that stupid maybe i will use it later anyway thx christiandev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a more detailed answer, set the **Link column** as `NOT NULL` and set the default value to be your URL.  This was, if the user / news editor doesn't enter a value, your URL will be added to the field.  The advantage of this is that you don't need any code to check for NULL etc.

Also, make sure the UI *validates* the URL that's added with regular expression, in case a rogue value is added.

If you want to alter it in code, you could try something like this...

```
public class News
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<News> GetNews()
    {
        var news = new List<News> {new News {Title = "News1", Url = "NewsURL"}, 
                                   new News {Title = "News1"}};
        return news.AsQueryable(); 
    }
}
```

You could then take out the list with no links and update them with your link...

```
var news = new News();
var initialNews = news.GetNews();

var newsWithLink = initialNews.Where(n => n.Url != null);
var newsWithOutLink = initialNews.Where(n => n.Url == null);

foreach (var newsItem in newsWithOutLink)
{
   newsItem.Url = "MyURL";
}

var newsToDisplay = newsWithLink.Concat(newsWithOutLink);
```

I've just put that small example together to show how to update the links.

Comment: thank you very much, i did like you said with the DB default link :D

Comment: No problem, I think that's the cleaner and more efficient approach :)